# Sort a collection by multiple fields

Tags: javascript, sorting, backbone.js, collections

How can I sort the models of a collection by two of their attributes?

Here is what I have so far:

```
 Character = Backbone.Model.extend();

 Characters = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Character,
     comparator: function(character){
         return [character.get('children') != undefined, character.get('age')]
     }
 });

 var myCharacters = new Characters([
     { name: 'Cersei',   age: 32, children: 3 },
     { name: 'Aemon',    age: 100             },
     { name: 'Tyrion',   age: 24              },
     { name: 'Stannis',  age: 33, children: 1 },
     { name: 'Daenerys', age: 14              }
     { name: 'Tywin',    age: 54, children: 3 },
     { name: 'Arya',     age: 9               },
 ]);

 myCharacters.sort;
```

The models should be sorted by `children` (do they have children or not), then by `age` (from oldest to youngest).
The resulting order would be : Tywin, Stannis, Cersei, Aemon, Tyrion, Daenerys, Arya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.

```
 Characters = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: Character,
     comparator: function(c){
         return [c.get('children') ? 0 : 1, 1/c.get('age')];
    }
 });
```

The `sort` method orders from smallest value to largest value.
If the character has children, the comparator will return `[0, (1/age)]`
Else (no children) it will return `[1, (1/age)]`

The characters will be ordered like this:

```
 Tywin    [0, 0.019]  
 Stannis  [0, 0.030]  
 Cersei   [0, 0.031]  
 Aemon    [1, 0.010]  
 Tyrion   [1, 0.042]  
 Daenerys [1, 0.071]  
 Arya     [1, 0.111]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `comparator` function needs to take to arguments (a, b) and return

- -1 if a is before b
- 0 if they're equal
- 1 if b is before a

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsort

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

comparator: function(char1,char2){

```
     var child1 = char1.get("children");
    var child2 = char2.get('children');
    var ageDiff = char1.get("age") - char1.get("age");
    if(child1 && child2){
        var diff = child1 - child2;
        if(diff !=0) return diff;
        return  ageDiff;
    }
    if(!child1 && !child2) return ageDiff;
    if(child1) return 1;
    return -1;
}
```